# Bootcamp problems have left my hard drive a mess

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

I have been trying to install Windows 8.1 via Bootcamp, and have had several problems that have resulted in failures (those are perhaps a different post). I'm using Yosemite.  Currently when I run disk utility I have two partitions, one of which I can't reclaim.

Booting into recovery mode, and listing my disk makes me think things are pretty messed up, as it returns:

```
-bash-3.2# diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         121.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *3.0 TB     disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         2.7 TB     disk1s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk1s3
/dev/disk2
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        *1.3 GB     disk2
   1:        Apple_partition_map                         30.7 KB    disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS OS X Base System        1.3 GB     disk2s2
/dev/disk3
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           *2.8 TB     disk3
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2, disk1s2
                                 1A190A54-1B4C-4F40-B8EF-92ABE794152D
                                 Unencrypted Fusion Drive
/dev/disk4
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *5.2 MB     disk4
/dev/disk5
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *524.3 KB   disk5
/dev/disk6
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *524.3 KB   disk6
/dev/disk7
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *524.3 KB   disk7
/dev/disk8
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *524.3 KB   disk8
/dev/disk9
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *524.3 KB   disk9
/dev/disk10
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *6.3 MB     disk10
/dev/disk11
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *2.1 MB     disk11
/dev/disk12
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *1.0 MB     disk12
/dev/disk13
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *524.3 KB   disk13
/dev/disk14
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *524.3 KB   disk14
/dev/disk15
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *1.0 MB     disk15
/dev/disk16
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *6.3 MB     disk16
/dev/disk17
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *16.0 GB    disk17
   1:                 DOS_FAT_32 WININSTALL              16.0 GB    disk17s1
```

I think disk4 on are junk sitting around for no reason.  How would I get rid of these so i can use disk utility to put that space back in my main partition?  The listing confuses me also because I was attempting to install windows on a 200gb partition, which doesn't seem to show.

results of diskutil cs list:

```
-bash-3.2# diskutil cs list
CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group 344E2BCC-9C6F-4CDB-A6D9-62ADAF11B572
    =========================================================
    Name:         Macintosh HD
    Status:       Online
    Size:         2796636491776 B (2.8 TB)
    Free Space:   143360 B (143.4 KB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume BE974D54-B1A8-43A7-8984-660AD671C2F7
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    0
    |   Disk:     disk0s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     120988852224 B (121.0 GB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 395184CB-7AB5-4147-9F01-D4D5A4AE60D2
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    1
    |   Disk:     disk1s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     2675647639552 B (2.7 TB)
    |
    +-> Logical Volume Family 297FCAC7-EEE1-45A4-95D2-CFC237CC4295
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Status:       Unlocked
        Encryption Type:         None
        Conversion Status:       NoConversion
        Conversion Direction:    -none-
        Has Encrypted Extents:   No
        Fully Secure:            No
        Passphrase Required:     No
        |
        +-> Logical Volume 1A190A54-1B4C-4F40-B8EF-92ABE794152D
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:                  disk3
            Status:                Online
            Size (Total):          2790449479680 B (2.8 TB)
            Conversion Progress:   -none-
            Revertible:            No
            LV Name:               Macintosh HD
            Volume Name:           Macintosh HD
            Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
```

Answer (score 1):

The partition map as well as the diskutil & diskutil cs listings looks completely valid.

Explanation:

- disk0: SSD part of a Fusion disk
- disk1: HDD part of a Fusion disk
- disk2: OS X base system (a recovery system mounted from disk1s3 or "downloaded" from Apple via Internet Recovery Mode)
- disk3: CoreStorage volume on disk0s2 & disk1s2
- disk4 - disk16: RAM disks needed in either recovery mode for temporary files
- disk17: Windows installer thumb drive

To install Windows with Boot Camp Assistant some free disk space is needed. To accomplish this the Core Storage Volume Group (including some other CoreStorage items) have to be resized. This is done by resizing the Physical Volume (disk1s2) on the HDD part and the inferior Logical Volume).

Usually the Physical Volume of the HDD part has a size of ~3 TB on a 3.1 TB Fusion disk and ~1 TB on a 1.1 TB Fusion disk. After choosing an arbitrary size for the Windows partition in BCA the PV and the LV will be resized accordingly.

Comparing it with my 3.1 TB Fusion disk you have chosen to assign ~320 GB to your Windows partition.

---

This assignment failed and no Windows partition was created. If BCA would have been successful your disk1 would look like this:

```
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *3.0 TB     disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         2.7 TB     disk1s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk1s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                324.0 GB   disk1s4
```

A failing Windows installation with BCA on a Fusion disk (with a CoreStorage stack) usually requires to completely backup your data with a backup app (i.e Time Machine), to rebuild/repartition the Fusion disk and to restore your old OS X system or restore it from scratch. The errors in the partition map and the CS stack following a failed Windows installation are usually not recoverable with the repair feature of Disk Utility.